# How to instantiate subclasses in superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class Base{
    protected Base instantiate() {//Should return an instance of the subclass that this method has been called from


    }
}

public class Sub1 extends Base {

}

public class Sub2 extends Base {

}

public static void main(String[] a) {
    Sub1 sub1 = new Sub1();
    Sub2 sub2 = new Sub2();
    Sub1 ss = sub1.instantiate();//should return a new instance of Sub1 
    Sub2 s = sub2.instantiate();//should return a new instance of Sub2
}
```

How can i  instantiate subclasses in superclass. In other words i need to know the implementation of the instantiate() method in Base class in above code.

**Edit**: This is part of the actual code:
the base class is:

```
     /**
         * Any class that extends this class should override the TABLE_NAME
         *
         * @author sSh
         */
        public class Model {

            protected static final String TABLE_NAME = null;

            private void createRecord() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {


            }

            private void updateRecord() {  

            }

            public ResultSet getAllRecords() { 

                //This is the method--that returns instance of the subclass that this method has 
   // been called from
            }

            public void saveRecord() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

            }


        }
```

The Model class should be the Base class of all the models.
so if we have PatientModel it would be something like this:

```
public class PatientModel extends Model{

        protected static final TABLE_NAME = "patient";

        //...fields and methods


    }


    public static void main(String[] a){
        PatientModel.getAllRecords();//this will return all the records in patient table as patient objects

    }
```

Comment: Although you've written `Sub2.instantiate();`, Java is actually calling `Sub1.instantiate();` The call to `instantiate()` has no concept of _caller_ or _calling class_.

Comment: You can't do that. If you know what class you want to instantiate, why not just call `new Sub1()` or `new Sub2()`?

Comment: can you pass an argument to `instantiate()`?

Comment: I suppose you want to do more than just creating an new instante in this static method. If so, please describe. Otherwise this method doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can not inherit static method in subclasses, your concept is wrong. Please edit your answer before someone downgrade it.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Actually the base class is a base database Model and i have done something like this (instantiating subclass in superclass) in php(new static()) and I was wondering if i could do this in java.

Comment: Actually i am looking for an equivalent for new static() in php. and this is part of my design pattern...

Comment: @gandalf You may use a factory instead. There is nothing like new static in java.

Answer (score 2):

You cant do that in this way, because you cant override static methods.

What you can do is that you create a BaseService class which do this job.

snippet:

```
public class BaseService {
      ....
      public static Base instantiate(Class<? extends Base> clazz) {
          //create the new instance based upon the parameter
      }
}
```

in main:

```
 Base base = BaseService.instantiate(Sub1.class);
```

or if you want the Sub1 instance as a Sub1 typed variable, you should cast.

Comment: I'm sorry the method doesn't have to be static. i should edit the question. i just made it static to make it more logical.

Comment: Then why do you want to use a method to instantiate? Why dont you use the constructor instead?

Comment: well i wrote the code this way to make it more easier to understand . although it doesn't matter that why i want to do this but i am gonna edit the question again.

Comment: Then use the constructor I would say. In this way, you just write `Base sub1 = new Sub1()`

Comment: It is also a possibility. I didnt want to mention that because I thought the OP is not familiar with Java.